# Trying to access data in Console.Log

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, console

I have a function that runs an ajax call to see if a file exists using the following code

```
function doesItExist(filenamePath) {

  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: filenamePath,
    type:'HEAD'
  });

}
```

When I try to read that in console.log using

```
console.log(doesItExist(some path));
```

I'm getting the following:

```
{readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
readyState: 4
getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)
statusCode: ƒ (a)
abort: ƒ (a)
state: ƒ ()
always: ƒ ()
then: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (a)
pipe: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
success: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
responseText: ""
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
__proto__: Object
```

It seems that I'm only able to access what's in the { } at the top, I can't access anything from "readyState: 4" and below. How can I do that, specifically the "status: 404"?

Thanks.

Side Note: Even if the file is found, it provides a similar response except "Status: 200" obviously.

Help please?

Comment: I've just removed the comment that annoyed you so much. Please note anyway that comments in Stack Overflow are not aimed at providing answers; they can and should be used to provide hints or request clarifications.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it's not that it annoyed me so much. As my response to you began, I thanked you for your comment. I just hoped for help, rather than what you did share. I will post the answer that is currently working for me in a reply soon.

Comment: I'm afraid this was nothing but a misunderstanding, probably due to my poor explanation. In your answer you explain you need to define callback functions, which is exactly what I was trying to say. Never mind, I'm glad you got it fixed.

Comment: No problems. Now I'm having issues making the function wait before jQuery goes through a FOR loop. jQuery.when() I think is that way to go. Not sure where I'm going wrong through.

Comment: I think I solved it by using jQuery.each instead of a For Loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I've figured it out. I have tried to explain my process in hopes that this helps someone running into the same problem.

### The Function

My original function does exactly what it's meant to do which is to check if the file (in the form of a URL) exists. The reason you would do it this way is so that the AJAX call only returns the headers of the URL without downloading anything. This way, you can find out whether:

1. File is Found (**Status 200**), or
2. File not found (**Status 404**)

Here's the function:

```
function doesItExist(filenamePath) {

  return jQuery.ajax({
    type:'HEAD',
    url: filenamePath
  });

}
```

Now I need to call that function so that I can use the data (the response) in the rest of my cose.

### Calling the Function

Here is where I was wrong.

What I was doing before was try to **console.log** the AJAX call. That's not going to give me any helpful response unless I tell the AJAX call exactly what I need from it and what part of the call I need.

```
doesItExist(some path).done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("XHR: " + (jqXHR.status));
});
```

To strip this down a little, I am calling the function as you would call any other function:

`doesItExist(parameters);`

With an AJAX call, however, you can get various responses based on whether the call was successful or not. You do that by using the callbacks:

1. `.done()` when successful
2. `.fail()` when unsuccessful (there's an error)
3. `.always()` runs regardless of a success or an error
4. `.then` (not important for this)

Using these callbacks, we can then get results from the jqXHR which is the jQuery (**jq**) XML HttpRequest (**XHR**).

Here's more on the subject: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/